# jCarousel navigation along with looperslider not working

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

I get the following errors when I click thumbnails in jCarousel script of this page (along with loopedslider plugin) :
( http://www.mamaisonmoncondo.ca/propriete/maison-a-etages-a-vendre-lancienne-lorette ) :

Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object][rel="2"]

But it seems to work properly on that example demo page : http://demo.woothemes.com/estate/property/desert-wing-house/

This is surely a very easy thing to fix but I couldn't figure it out by myself ... any help would be very helpful :)

Comment: Try removing `loopedSlider` plugin.

Comment: In fact, jCarousel is supposed to work with loopedslider together; I edited my question with a working example of the script. I can't see what is causing the problem in my case :/

Answer (score 0):

LoopedSlider plugin doesn't work with jQuery 1.8.3 (or at least in my case). I downgraded jquery to 1.8.0 and it now works.